# Restrict Element to URL

Tags: xml, xsd, atom-feed

I have this existing XSD and it's trying to restrict a value to a URL but it's not working.  The id is blank and the document still validates.  It also validates when I enter in any text.

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
...

<xsd:complexType name="feedType">
<xsd:choice minOccurs="3" maxOccurs="unbounded">
    <xsd:element name="id" type="atom:idType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
...

<xsd:complexType name="idType">
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation>
            The Atom id construct is defined in section 4.2.6 of the format spec.
        </xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:simpleContent>
        <xsd:extension base="xsd:anyURI">
            <xsd:attributeGroup ref="atom:commonAttributes"/>
        </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:simpleContent>
</xsd:complexType>
```

............

```
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom ../XMLschemas/atom/2005/v/0.2/atom.xsd">
    <id>https://mydomain.com</id>
```

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "XSD: " and such. That's what the tags are for.

Comment: @John, yes I don't know why this was set up this way but anyway the other element restrictions are working, it's just the id that has the problem.  Petru, I'm using Altova XMLSpy and Eclipse validators.  Both have the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`anyURI` also allows relative URIs, and afaik an empty string is a valid relative URI. You might add a `pattern` facet to require "://" to get closer to what you want.

As the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#anyURI) says,

> ... in practice the [anyURI] definition imposes only very modest
>   obligations on minimally conforming processors.